# Fatal error: Call to a member function bind_param() on a non-object in webserver

Tags: webserver

```
<php>    
$ueberpruefeAufSVNREintrag = $conn->prepare('Select  P_SVNR from p_Patient where P_SVNR = ? ');
        $ueberpruefeAufSVNREintrag  -> bind_param('s', $Svnr);
        $ueberpruefeAufSVNREintrag  -> execute();
        $resul = $ueberpruefeAufSVNREintrag  -> get_result();
        $rowav = $resul -> fetch_assoc();
        $ueberpruefeAufSVNREintrag  -> close();
</php>
```

I get this error in

my webspace in localhost it works fine.
Anyone an idea why?

Comment: Is this PHP? Please add the appropriate tags.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using PHP and MySQLi (you should *really* add those tags).

Apparently `$conn->prepare` didn't return an object. Most likely it returned `false` which is what it does in case of error. The reason preparing failed may have several causes. One possibility: there is a syntax error in the query. This doesn't seem the case, but it could also be that there is another kind of error, for instance if `p_Patient` doesn't exist. Other causes could be that you didn't select the right database or didn't make a connection at all.

So, although I can't tell you the exact error, I *can* tell you that you should check the result value of all those functions, check what they return (for instance `false` in case of error), and use the appropriate properties and methods to get more error information, like [mysqli::$error](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php).

Comment: Perhaps making the connection with the database failed. Different connection, different password, there is no way to tell. The code you posted *could* work, but something goes wrong somewhere in the process. You really have to use all the feedback you can get from those functions to tell you what is wrong. There is no way for us to tell.